# Unexpected status line when making post request from android device

Tags: java, android, http-post

Hi I have an Android app that needs to connect to an API (currently running locally) to authenticate the user, so I'm trying to send a POST request with a JSON object as the request body but whenever I try to login I get the following error:

```
Unexpected status line: ��
           java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ��
```

Here's my code:

```
    String API_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8443/api/";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.connect();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("customerId", 1);
                jsonObject.put("password" , mPassword);
                jsonObject.put("username" , mEmail);

                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
                Log.d("REQUEST BODY", jsonObject.toString());
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("RESPONSE", String.valueOf(response));
                if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    return getStringFromInputStream(bis);
                }
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
```

Can anyone please tell me what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT**

Not sure if this helps but the problem seems to occur when I call `urlConnection.getResponseCode();`.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are recycling the connection

try adding `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");`  before connecting

Comment: I've tried this before and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Are there any other HTTP calls that happen before this one? If so, you need to make sure that connection closes before you use this one

Comment: No this is the only HTTP call going on, this is inside my `LoginActivity` where I have a `UserLoginTask` that extends from `AsyncTask`, this where I make the HTTP POST request, and that's all my app has, I'm just trying to make the login work for now.